# How do i use Debug.Trace.trace in the state monad?

Tags: haskell

I want to keep track of changes in the state monad. This does not work:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ snd $ execState compute initialState

traceThis :: (Show a) => a -> a
traceThis x = trace ("test: " ++ show x) x

compute :: State ([Row], Integer) String
compute = liftM traceThis $ get >>= \(rs, result) -> put (rs, result + 3) >> return "foo"
```

Nothing gets printed (except the end result from the print in the main function which has correctly been updated).

Any ideas or alternatives to track state? I want to use this for checking correctness of a project euler solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem in your case is that `traceThis` is never getting evaluated. Haskell is a lazy language, so it only evaluates expressions that are needed. And since you don't evaluate computation result, only the state, it's not necessary to evaluate `traceThis` inside `compute`. If you print for example

```hs
print $ evalState compute initialState
```

then the result value of the stateful computation gets evaluated along with calling `traceThis`.

A better option would be to define a monadic function that forces printing the result value whenever any part of the monadic computation is evaluated:

```hs
traceState :: (Show a) => a -> State s a
traceState x = state (\s -> trace ("test: " ++ show x) (x, s))

compute :: State ([Int], Integer) String
compute = get >>= \(rs, result) -> put (rs, result + 3)
              >> return "foo"
              >>= traceState
```

**Update:** This can be generalized to an arbitrary monad. The main point is that `trace` must wrap the monadic computation, not just the value inside, so that it gets evaluated when `>>=` is evaluated, regardless of whether the value inside is evaluated or not:

```hs
traceMonad :: (Show a, Monad m) => a -> m a
traceMonad x = trace ("test: " ++ show x) (return x)
```

Comment: Very nice! Once i don't need logging anymore i can turn it off by deleting a single expression.

Comment: @somesoaccount Updated the answer with a more general solution.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative.  Use `StateT s IO` as your monad:

```
compute :: StateT ([Row], Integer) IO String
compute = do
    (rs, result) <- get
    lift $ putStrLn "result = " ++ show result
    put (rs, result + 3)
    return "foo"
```

Now you can interleave `IO` actions anywhere using `lift`.

To learn more about monad transformers, I recommend you read the excellent introduction: [Monad Transformers - Step by Step](http://www.grabmueller.de/martin/www/pub/Transformers.en.html).

Comment: This seems like a simple solution, only culprit for me is using monad transformers since i heard they are slow and i need good performance here.

Comment: You are already paying for the monad transformer, whether or not you realize it.  `State s` is just a type synonym for `StateT s Identity`.  [Proof](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.3.0.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#t:State).  Also, most concerns about monad transformer performance are overblown.  I recommend you benchmark it yourself and compare to the performance of `Debug.Trace` before you dismiss it.

Answer (score 5):

When you call `execState`, you are just asking for the final state, not for the value returned by the `compute` function. `liftM`, on the other hand, lifts your `traceThis` function to an action in the `State` monad that doesn't touch the state. Thus, due to laziness, `traceThis` will only be called if you force the *value* returned by `compute` to be evaluated. In general, for `trace` to work properly, you have to be sure that the value that you call it on gets evaluated.

`Debug.Trace` is generally only suitable for quick debugging - it is not a very powerful logging system and can be difficult to use due to laziness. If you are looking for a way to do this more robustly, you could add another element (perhaps a list of strings) to your state tuple and have the `compute` function write log messages to that.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I thought of laziness aswell but since the result was printed i discarded this possibility...
I'm not sure if i like to add extensive logging since it will be removed in the future for performance reasons.